# MYSql Trigger statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

I can't seem to get one of the triggers im trying to make to work at the moment it looks like this (has been messed around with alot in an attempt to get it to work so probably doesn't make any sense now)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insertproductebay` AFTER INSERT ON `product`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO eBayLinked
(product_id,company_id,eBay_ID,ebay_token_id,ebay_username) 
SELECT ebay_token_id,ebay_username
FROM
'company'
WHERE
'company_id' = 'company_id'
  VALUES
      (NEW.product_id,NEW.company_id,NEW.eBay_ID,ebay_token_id,ebay_username)
```

Comment: you have several problems. One is back-ticks, two is column count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) and [`INSERT ... VALUES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) syntaxes in that way.  However, you can provide literal values in a select list, thusly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertproductebay AFTER INSERT ON product FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO eBayLinked
    (product_id, company_id, eBay_ID, ebay_token_id, ebay_username) 
  SELECT NEW.product_id, NEW.company_id, NEW.eBay_ID, ebay_token_id, ebay_username
  FROM   company
  WHERE  company_id = NEW.company_id
```

Comment: @jamescox welcome to the stack. Please mark this answer as the Accepted Answer by giving it the Green Check Mark under the arrows to the left of the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following makes it past the 1065 error

Care must be taken to use back-ticks around table and column names, and not to use single quotes there.

```
drop trigger if exists `insertproductebay`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `insertproductebay` AFTER INSERT ON `product`
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO eBayLinked
(product_id,company_id,eBay_ID,ebay_token_id,ebay_username) 
SELECT NEW.product_id,NEW.company_id,NEW.eBay_ID,ebay_token_id,ebay_username
FROM `company`
WHERE `company_id` = 'company_id'
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The remaining problem as I see it could be what are you meaning by

```
WHERE `company_id` = 'company_id'
```

in a trigger. Because a trigger is a faceless piece of code that runs in the background, succeeding or failing silently. In other words, there is no user interface associated with it.